# Is there anyway to map/convert 468 landmarks by Mediapipe to 68 landmarks?

Tags: dlib, vision, mediapipe

I am trying to compare the ground truth facial landmarks (68 landmarks) with Mediapipe landmark detection (which are 468 landmarks). In order to do so, I think I need to map the 468 landmarks to 68 landmarks in some way. My possible solution is to manually find the indices closest to each of the 68 landmarks and output those. But I am not sure of the accuracy here. Can someone help me in this regard? Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert on the subject, but I think there is no direct way to do a conversion, this is because the mapping is different from one side to the other.

To this I have taken the same idea that you mention and I have extracted the closest points.

So this is the code that I have added to the code that mediapipe proposes for my use in dlib. The final result is not so wrong considering that many points are coincident with each other.

At the beginning of the MediaPipe Face Mesh code example you should add a list which is a selection of points that match dlib 68 landmarks:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh

#New Add
landmark_points_68 = [162,234,93,58,172,136,149,148,152,377,378,365,397,288,323,454,389,71,63,105,66,107,336,
                  296,334,293,301,168,197,5,4,75,97,2,326,305,33,160,158,133,153,144,362,385,387,263,373,
                  380,61,39,37,0,267,269,291,405,314,17,84,181,78,82,13,312,308,317,14,87]
```

In the MediaPipe Face Mesh code example look for the line:

```
for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
```

then add the following:

```
        landmarks_extracted = []
        for index in landmark_points_68:
            x = int(face_landmarks.landmark[index].x * width)
            y = int(face_landmarks.landmark[index].y * height)
            landmarks_extracted.append((x, y))
```

now that list (landmarks extracted) you can use it in your code

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time for finding indices of all 68 dlib landmarks myself!